# Joomla - Section Blog Layout - How to hide section title

Tags: joomla

I'm working on a site in Joomla. I have my main menu and from that i have created the home page as a "Section Blog Layout". I want to display article titles and hide the section title, currently i can only manage to show/hide the article title, I cannot remove the section title.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Steph

Comment: How exactly is that programming related? I think you will have better luck getting an answer in the joomla forum.

Answer (score 2):

i was having the same problem as you. I was not able to find the answer anywhere because i was searching for "hide section title in blog layout". Turns out that it is actually considered the page title and not "section titled".

Anyways, to fix this you have to go to open up the editor for the menu where you posted this blog layout menu item. On the right had side of the page, where you see all the parameter setting, there should be a tab called "Parameters (system). There you have the option Show Page Tittle Yes or No, select No and you'll be set.

Hope this helped. This little problem was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember if there is an option under the menu item for Section Blog layout. If not, can you do a simple template override and remove the heading?

If you're not sure how to proceed, let me know.